# Trouble using fork() to calculate a total sum of received command line arguments

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm trying to calculate the sum based off of sets of numbers received from the command line and I use a companion program called worker to due the computation for me. If the amount of numbers received is odd, it will add a zero to the amount of numbers to make the set even.

This is the flow of the program in an understandable way(credit to Alok):

An example will make this clearer:

Let's say you want to add 7 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

./coordinator 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1. input = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0]
2. n = len(input) = 8
3. m = n/2 = 4
4. output = [0 0 0 0]
5. We fork 4 process, first process gets [1 2], second gets [3 4], ...
6. The 4 processes return 3, 7, 11, 7 respectively, which we assign to output.
7. output has 4 elements, so we allocate space for 4+1 = 5 elements for the new input.
8. set input = [3 7 11 7 0]
9. n = len(input) = 5
10. m = n/2 = 2
11. output = [0 0]
12. We fork 2 processes, first gets [3 7], second gets [11 7]
13. The 2 processes return 10, 18, which we assign to output.
14. output has 2 elements, so we allocate space for 2+1 = 3 elements for the new input.
15. set input = [10 18 0]
16. n = len(input) = 3
17. m = n/2 = 1
18. output = [0]
19. We fork one process, which gets [10 18]
20. The process returns 28, which we assign to output.
21. output has 1 element, so we are done.

Although on this particular set of numbers I get:

```
Process ID: 15195 
Sum of 1 and 2 is 3 

Process ID: 15196 
Sum of 3 and 4 is 7 

Process ID: 15197 
Sum of 5 and 6 is 11 

Process ID: 15198 
Sum of 7 and 0 is 7 

*** glibc detected *** ./coordinator: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x080ec048 ***
```

Followed by a list of heap errors.

I believe I am not reallocating the size of the pointers correctly in which I attempt to redirect the old output to the new input after the first call to next_step(). So it's trying to put data into a part of memory for which there is no space.

**UPDATE:**

@Norman

This is the output I receive:

```
==3585== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3585== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3585== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3585== Command: ./coordinator 1 2 3 4
==3585== 
calc: 2:
input[0]: 1
input[1]: 2
input[2]: 3
input[3]: 4
==3585== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==3585==    at 0x4076186: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4079A81: vfprintf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4080F7F: printf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x8048833: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
==3585== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3585==    at 0x407618E: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4079A81: vfprintf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4080F7F: printf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x8048833: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
==3585== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3585==    at 0x4077877: vfprintf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4080F7F: printf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x8048833: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
==3585== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3585==    at 0x407789B: vfprintf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x4080F7F: printf (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.10.1.so)
==3585==    by 0x8048833: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
input[4]: 0
==3586== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3586== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3586== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3586== Command: ./worker 1 2
==3586== 
Process ID: 3586 
Sum of 1 and 2 is 3 

==3586== 
==3586== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3586==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3586==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3586== 
==3586== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3586== 
==3586== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3586== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
==3587== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3587== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3587== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3587== Command: ./worker 3 4
==3587== 
Process ID: 3587 
Sum of 3 and 4 is 7 

==3587== 
==3587== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3587==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3587==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3587== 
==3587== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3587== 
==3587== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3587== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
==3585== Invalid write of size 4
==3585==    at 0x8048A3A: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585==  Address 0x417f0b4 is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3585==    at 0x4024C6C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==3585==    by 0x4024CF6: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:476)
==3585==    by 0x8048A25: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
==3588== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3588== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3588== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3588== Command: ./worker 3 7
==3588== 
Process ID: 3588 
Sum of 3 and 7 is 10 

==3588== 
==3588== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3588==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3588==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3588== 
==3588== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3588== 
==3588== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3588== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
==3585== Invalid read of size 4
==3585==    at 0x8048AB5: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585==  Address 0x417f0e0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==3585==    at 0x4024C6C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==3585==    by 0x4024CF6: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:476)
==3585==    by 0x8048A77: main (in /home/bryan/cpp/coordinator)
==3585== 
The final sum is: 0==3585== 
==3585== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3585==     in use at exit: 28 bytes in 2 blocks
==3585==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==3585== 
==3585== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3585==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==3585==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3585==      possibly lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==3585==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3585==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3585== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3585== 
==3585== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3585== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3585== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

Comment: ChangePointers looks like a function, but it's imbedded inside another function, which is not allowed.  is this supposed to be a function?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to still have access to the input and output array. I thought I would lose access to the pointers if I them outside of the main method. Was this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: Why are you doing this with multiple processes?  And waiting for those processes right after spawning them?  And I don't see any IPC...

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  You're using the return code as the sum.  Are you aware that typically this is only in the range 0-127?  I think it would be much more appropriate to use pipes or something.  And the point that you're synchronously waiting for the processes immediately after launching still stands -- this will negate any benefit of doing it in multiple processes.

Comment: @asveikau - It is clearly a contrived homework assignment.  He has to fulfill the requirements even if they are stupid.

Comment: I'm aware of the constraints I was given. I keep getting heap errors, so I'm not sure where to go from here even after adding Aman's changes.

Comment: @Duck I agree... if you wanted to teach recursion this could be done as a single process w/o the need for fork. In fact, the worker should be in the "child" part of the if anyway and communicate back via IPC/Pipes. Forking then executing another process doesn't make sense.

Comment: I rolled back the edit that deleted the code because the question becomes nigh-on meaningless without it.  As a general comment, using fork() for this is obviously a sledgehammer to crack a tiny nut.  The object of the exercise, then, must be to think about how to coordinate processes - rather than to solve the specific problem (because there are a multitude of far simpler ways to solve the problem).

Comment: @John, I agree with everyone what has said so far. I believe I am close to the solution though because it is printing out what I want to now, but I keep getting segmentation faults near the end of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about writing a function, let's call it `step_once()`, which will take `input` with `n` numbers, and write to the corresponding `output` with `m = n/2` elements.  `n` above is the number of input numbers + 1, with the last element of `input` equal to 0.

In your driver function, let's say `main()`: if `output` contains 1 number, you are done.  Otherwise, you reallocate `input` to contain `n_new = m+1` elements, reallocate `output` to contain `m_new = n_new/2` elements, and call the function `step_once()` again.  You keep doing this until you get one number:

```
function next_step(input, output, n, m):
    n := number of input numbers # this is 1 greater than
                                 # the number of numbers being summed
    m := n / 2 # C division
    n_children := m
    i := 0
    while i < m:
        fork worker with input[2*i] and input[2*i+1]
        get result in output[i]
        i := i + 1

function main:
    set n := length(input) + 1
    set m := n/2
    allocate memory for input # n+1 elements, last = 0
    allocate memory for output # m elements
    set values in input
    while True:
        next_step(input, output, n, m)
        if length or output == 1:
             done, return
        else:
            set n := length(output) + 1
            set m := n/2
            allocate space for new_input # n elements
            set new_input := output + [0]
            free input and output
            set input := new_input
            allocate memory for output # m elements
```

The advantage is that you can test your `next_step()` function to make sure it works and thus makes debugging easier.

An example will make this clearer:

Let's say you want to add 7 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1. `input` = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0]
2. `n` = len(`input`) = 8
3. `m` = `n/2` = 4
4. `output` = [0 0 0 0]
5. We fork 4 process, first process gets [1 2], second gets [3 4], ...
6. The 4 processes return 3, 7, 11, 7 respectively, which we assign to `output`.
7. `output` has 4 elements, so we allocate space for 4+1 = 5 elements for the new `input`.
8. set `input` = [3 7 11 7 0]
9. `n` = len(`input`) = 5
10. `m` = `n/2` = 2
11. `output` =  [0 0]
12. We fork 2 processes, first gets [3 7], second gets [11 7]
13. The 2 processes return 10, 18, which we assign to `output`.
14. `output` has 2 elements, so we allocate space for 2+1 = 3 elements for the new `input`.
15. set `input` = [10 18 0]
16. `n` = len(`input`) = 3
17. `m` = `n/2` = 1
18. `output` = [0]
19. We fork one process, which gets [10 18]
20. The process returns 28, which we assign to `output`.
21. output has 1 element, so we are done.

Comment: This line: set input := output + [0]

Does that mean populate input with outputs data or redirect the pointers? But if you free the memory right before that, won't I lose the arguments stored in output?

Comment: @ray2k, good point.  Fixed.  You don't really need to copy data over from `output` to `input`, you can just set the `input` pointer to point to `output`, but then you have to be more careful about the number of elements to sum. That is also not too hard, but I wanted to avoid mentioning that.  Once you get this working, you can think about further optimization.

Comment: @Alok, Hello I fixed my code as per the pseudocode that you gave me but it is giving me segmentation fault errors out the wazoo. I updated my original post with this. Could you give me any feedback on my new code? Thank you.

Comment: Your main trouble seems to be `*input = *new_input` line: you want to copy the elements in a loop, something like: `for(i=0; i < m; ++i) new_input[i] = input[i];`, followed by `free(input);` and `input = new_input;`.  I haven't looked at other parts of the code in detail yet.  Good luck!

Comment: I've worked on my program over night and I'm still stuck at the reallocation part after the first call to next_step(). I'm afraid I won't finish this. I took the advice of others on here from a previous post and I'm doing it the right way, but still receiving new heap errors. I updated my original post to make clear of this new problem.

Comment: @ray2k: the first thing you need to do is start from scratch.  You should eliminate most of your variables, such as `length`, `calc`, etc.  Keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to change the pointers.

void ChangePointers(int **input, int **output)

and

ChangePointers(&input, &output);

Comment: I made the necessary changes, but I am still getting fault errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ray, it's hard to know what's wrong without seeing more details about the errors.  If, as I suspect, these are run-time errors, can you run the code under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  `valgrind` is extremely effective at pinpointing memory errors; with your application you'll want

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes ./coordinator 1 2 3 4
```

**EDIT**: OK, with the valgrind errors we can see that (a) you're passing something dodgy to `printf` (if you compile with `-g` you'll get the exact line number), and also you're calling `realloc` but not on a pointer you got back from `malloc`.  Maybe you've done some pointer arithmetic?

Can't say more without seeing the code, but I hope you find valgrind helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of off-by-one errors:

1. `for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)`
2. `while(calc > 0)`